# Half-life of a radioactive substance?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework

> After 4.27 minutes 99.99% of a radioactive substance is present. What is the half-life of the radioactive substance?

What code would I use to solve this problem? I don't know how to start it.

Comment: First, I'd figure out the mathematical formula and then I'd type that in.  (Use `E` for the natural log/exp base.)

Comment: `NDSolve[{
  Eliminate[{y'[t] == k*y[t], D[y'[t] == k*y[t], t]}, k], y[0] == 1, 
  y[4.27] == 0.9999,
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 1/2, Return[t, NDSolve]]}, y, {t, 0, 10^8}]` seems to work. Well, I think it's cute, but it's not the easiest way to explain....

Comment: `DSolve` is a bit trickier but gives a more accurate answer: `DSolveValue[{
  y[t] y''[t] == y'[t]^2, y[0] == 1, y[4.27] == 0.9999, ans[0] == 0,
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 1/2, ans[t] -> t]}, ans[10^8], {t, 0, 10^8}, 
 DiscreteVariables -> {ans}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[hl];
```

Solve for half-life:

```
 Quantile[ExponentialDistribution[Log[2]/hl], .0001] == 4.27 // FullSimplify
```

> 1. hl == 29595.9

Check that answer gives the correct .01% depletion at 4.27 units:

```
CDF[ExponentialDistribution[Log[2]/29595.9], 4.27]
```

> 0.0001

Next time, please show your work. If you don't understand the physics, physics.stackexchange.com is where to ask, and for the mathematics, math.stackexchange.com is where to ask.